# Why the rename of column not working when connect to redshift with ODBC?

Tags: odbc, amazon-redshift

I have a simple SQL that need to call RedShift through ODBC.
The SQL is like this

```
SELECT id as Tag From SomeView
```

This just not working. It gives me the error

**DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42601] [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42601] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Tag'"
LINE 1: Select id As Tag From SomeView**

**Details:
DataSourceKind=Odbc
DataSourcePath=dsn=Amazon Redshift ODBC DSN
OdbcErrors=Table**

I tried

```
SELECT id as 'Tag' From SomeView
SELECT id Tag From SomeView
SELECT id 'Tag' From SomeView
```

None of them work. Only the one with no rename works.

```
SELECT id From SomeView
```

Why is that???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT id "Tag" From SomeView
```

`Tag` is a reserved word in Redshift, if you like to use reserved words as column names or aliases you need to use delimited identifiers (double quotes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never think about that! I knew that Tag is a Redshift reserved words, but I thought the renaming is done on client side. when you mention it and I 'wow' about it, and understand that the string was send to Redshift for executing.